# Атрибуты imgfield и bgimgfield - что это?

Tags: изображения, html, атрибуты

Здравствуйте! Помогите решить такую задачу, пожалуйста.

Получила вчера проект на SEO-оптимизацию. И не могу понять, что это за атрибуты прописаны к изображениям (imgfield) и div*ам (bgimgfield). Здесь:

```
<a href="/">
<img src="/bitrix/templates/url сайта/images/logo.png" imgfield="img" alt="Описание рисунка"></a>
```

И еще здесь:

```
<div class="t309__item item active" bgimgfield="img" id="bx_3218110189_355">
```

Поспрашивала поисковики, ничего вразумительного. Что-то есть насчет того, что к полям форм эти атрибуты могут применяться. Но в моем случае никакой формы тут нет. Обычный рисунок (логотип) и обычный блок.

Подскажите, мастера, что это и для чего? Версия html - 4.0. Сайт на Битрикс, но кое-где в data-атрибутах упоминается tilda. Предполагаю, что когда-то сей ресурс был написан на данном конструкторе, а потом перенесен на bitrix.

В стилях еще не разбиралась. Мне бы оно и не нужно совсем, стили css с seo мало связаны.
Понять надобно прежде, чем что-то с этим делать.
Буду очень благодарна за ответ.

Comment: это кастомеые атрибуты...  спроси тех кто их создовал...

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже думала, что просто пользовательские. Но, большим спецом себя не считаю, побоялась ошибиться.

Comment: @Наталья где это так атрибуты называют, если не секрет?

Comment: Мне на оптимизацию дали сайт. Написан верстальщиком одного из интернет-агентств СПб. Как мне предварительно сообщили, сайтов, им написанных, несколько и они не особенно хорошо ранжируются поисковиками. То есть мне с этим работать еще несколько недель. В принципе, там просто очень мало семантики и много вспомогательных блоков-оберток. И вот такие атрибуты. Я сама такое впервые увидела.

Comment: из-за этих атрибутов, кстати, код не проходит валидацию

Comment: Консорциум World Wide Web (W3C) https://www.w3.org/standards/ который устанавливает стандарты для кодирования HTML и CSS для веб - страниц не знает этих атрибуты https://www.w3schools.com/tags/

Comment: А если добавить к ним префикс data- код будет валиден?